# What is difference: AttributeCollection.Contains(TKey) vs AttributeCollection.ContainsKey(TKey)?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, contains

What is difference for `AttributeCollection.Contains(TKey)` and `AttributeCollection.ContainsKey(TKey)`? I doesn't see any difference in the [official manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.xrm.sdk.attributecollection?view=dynamics-general-ce-9).

```
var stuff = new Entity("abc_stuff");
stuff.Attributes.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>(
    "kvp", 12));
stuff.Attributes.Add("txt", "foo");
stuff.Attributes.Add("null", null);

var containsKvp = stuff.Attributes.Contains("kvp"); // true
var containsKvpKey = stuff.Attributes.ContainsKey("kvp"); // true

var containsTxt = stuff.Attributes.Contains("txt"); // true
var containsTxtKey = stuff.Attributes.ContainsKey("txt"); // true

var containsNull = stuff.Attributes.Contains("null"); // true
var containsNullKey = stuff.Attributes.ContainsKey("null"); // true

var containsFoo = stuff.Attributes.Contains("foo"); // false
var containsFooKey = stuff.Attributes.ContainsKey("foo"); // false
```

Comment: Try to do this: `stuff.Attributes.Add("test_1", "test_2");`  `stuff.Attributes.ContainsKey("test_2");` will return false but `stuff.Attributes.Contains("test_2");` will return true

Comment: @MohamadMousheimish you are mistaken. Both return `false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `Contains` calls the `ContainsKey` method internally. You can see the generated IL code.